# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile error

Tags: python, django, localhost

[TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7tWy.png)

when i try to upload a image file and enter submit this error pops up

please give me solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [ask].

Comment: it seems that the subject is already resolved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638374/expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-object-not-inmemoryuploadedfile